# npm error after installing Node.js: Cannot find module 'es6-promisify'

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, node-promisify

I have installed the latets version of Node.js for Windows. Whatever command I use I always get the same exception, i.e. when I type "npm -v" get this error message:

```
Cannot find module 'es6-promisify'
```

How to install "es6-promisify" when NPM is missing "es6-promisify" in the first place?

BTW, during the installation of Node.js a view dependencies try to access protected foldes inside external hard drives for no reason and the last error that stuck forever was the installation of Microsoft Visual Studio Code. It seems to me that those tools cannot be installed without giving 100% access to every folder on every partition you have. This seems wrong to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: Uninstall the NodeJs app from the system
Step 2: Goto the programFiles/nodejs -> *delete node_modules folder*
Step 3: Reinstall NodeJs app

By following these steps you can fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I found out a solution to this issue. I had to unplug all external drives, restart Windows, delete the folder "node_modules" manually and finally I started the Node.js msi to repair the installtion (copies files to node_modules again). After theses steps NPM is working again.

Remember: Reparing the installation without deleting the node_modules folder manually was not sufficient.

Comment: Great! Re-installing also wouldn't work for me. Deleted the node_modules and repairing installation by executing the MSI install again fixed the problem (no reboot required).